# Can't find control using FindControl

Tags: asp.net

Having trouble getting find control to find something, but it's returning null when the control does exist.

It's being called on an `asp:button click` (and no fields have display dynamic on them). The controls are labels, and have runat server e.t.c. I'm using Umbraco, was thinking going `Page.FindControl` might not work /w umbraco because it uses master pages? Here's the code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Reg_Name_Error" CssClass="error" runat="server" />

if (Page.FindControl("Reg_Name_Error") != null) { }
```

Comment: Where is the label, in the MasterPage?

Comment: yeh, cant find any controls on the page :(

Comment: the controls are in a conteplaceholder do i need to search in that?

Comment: Sorry not a ontentplaceholder but a <content

Comment: Add the relevant markup also..

Answer (score 3):

As you are using master page you have to write following code

```
ContentPlaceHolder content;
content = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("Your Content Place Holder Id");
```

Then write following code

```
if (content != null)
        {
            if (content.FindControl("Reg_Name_Error") != null)
```

Comment: you have to give your content place holder ID which is in your master page.